# How can i speed up an XWiki installation on debian?

Tags: debian, performance-tuning

We installed XWiki on Debian. Page load times in default config were about 2 seconds. Tuning the memory parameters according to the XWiki performanve guide brought it down to 1 second. But for a local installation on decent hardware without users this seems still really slow. What can we do?

Comment: What hardware are you running xwiki? Is a VM or physical server?

Comment: Collect metrics, examine metrics, discover bottlenecks, mitigate bottlenecks. Wash, rinse, repeat.

Comment: It's a VM on an HyperV server.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using stock version of xwiki - a bundle containing jars, jetty etc downloaded from xwiki.org - chances are you use HSQLDB as a data storage. [migrate your data to mysql](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/FAQ/How+to+migrate+from+HSQLDB+to+MySQL). my xwiki became much more responsive after doing that.

Comment: how fast?Whats ur p99 /avg page load time

Comment: @user93796 - running "ab -n 50000 -c 4 http://localhost:8090/xwiki/bin/view/Main/" gave me: Requests per second:    22145.87 [#/sec] , Time per request:       0.181 [ms], Time per request:       0.045 [ms]